# Numeric or value error using `dbms_random.string`

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I created a table called `LISTKOS`

```
create table LISTKOS (
  kostid    number,
  name      varchar2(50) not null,
  location  varchar2(50),
  constraint pk_listkos primary key (kostid)
);
```

Then I went on to create the trigger to auto-populate the primary key (`kostid`)

```
create or replace trigger LISTKOS
   before insert or update on LISTKOS
   for each row
begin
   if inserting and :new.kostid is null then 
      :new.kostid := dbms_random.string('x', 7);
   end if;
end;
/
```

I selected 'x' because I wanted it to be in alphanumeric form (and because the type of values for `kostid` as I described when creating the table is `number`)

The error message keeps appearing

```
ORA-06502: pl/sql numeric error
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the column as a `number` so you can't store alphanumeric data in it.  You can only store numeric data.  If you want to store alphanumeric data, you'd need to declare the column as `varchar2`. If you want to populate the primary key with a random number, you'd use the `dbms_random.value` function.

It almost certainly does not make sense to generate primary key values randomly however.  That is relatively expensive to generate and (depending on how busy your system is and what key ranges you allow) subject to collisions.  It would almost certainly make more sense to use a sequence.  It also doesn't make sense to assign the primary key value in an `on update` trigger.

```
create sequence kostid_seq
  start with 1
  increment by 1;

create or replace trigger LISTKOS
   before insert on LISTKOS
   for each row
begin
   if :new.kostid is null then 
      :new.kostid := kostid_seq.nextval;
   end if;
end;
```

Comment: From Oracle 12.1, it's even easier: we can use an `identity` column with the option `generated by default on null`.

Comment: True.  I assume that part of the goal is to learn about triggers here.

Comment: anyway, i tried to use that sequence command but i got this instead:  Errors: TRIGGER LISTKOS
Line/Col: 4/4 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: @ruru - Fair enough.  I missed a semicolon.  Updated my answer

Comment: @ruru - The much bigger issue with such approaches (using trigger with sequence, or identity column) arises if we are doing this on a column that is **primary key** and we allow the user to enter the id sometimes, while other times we use a sequence. Suppose the user enters valid id values (1, 2, 3) and then he tries to enter data without an id, relying on the default. The sequence value may be 1; then the insert will fail, as a violation of PK constraint. This kind of table definition is asking for big trouble.

Comment: thanks @mathguy now i understand a little bit about the general idea of primary keys. thats important lesson

Answer (score -1):

Trigger without used sequence `SQL`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LISTKOS BEFORE INSERT ON LISTKOS
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.kostid  is  null)
BEGIN SELECT nvl(max(kostid ),0)+1  INTO :NEW.kostid  FROM LISTKOS; END;
```